# Google Cloud function to read the document from Firestore secured with rules

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am a newbie to the Cloud Functions.

I have an Android app which calls the Cloud Function through callable client and Cloud Function(node.js/typescript) calls Firestore to read the data.

Cloud Function code :

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({credential : admin.credential.applicationDefault()});
exports.queryForData = functions.https.onCall((dats, context) => {
admin.firestore().collection('mydocument').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach( e => {
                    if(e.exists)
                    {
                    console.log("docs="+e.ref.path);
                    return {"data":e.data()};
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("No docs!!!!!")
                        return {"data":"empty"}
                    }
                })

            })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("error occurred"+error);
            return {error:error};
        });
    });
```

When my Android app calls this function I get an error message caught by catch block shows: `ERROR: Could not load the default credential` and asks to check the Google Cloud Service Key set up URL and I have set up the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** to point to the downloaded JSON file.

I have tried `initializeApp` with no arguments,with credential with `applicationDefault` and also `functions.config().firebase`

I have put console logs to see if the function is invoked and HTTP call is received, yes it is invoked. But seems like the issue is when I try to get the collection.

Firestore rule allows authenticated users to read the document.

I have gone through the video tutorials and the question asked here before as well but none seems to resolve my issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I initialize using the .json service account file. You can generate this from the Firebase console.

My initialization looksl ike thi

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./key.json");

const databaseURL = "https://xyz-prod.firebaseio.com";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL
});

const db = admin.firestore()
const itemsRef = db.collection("items")
```

Comment: where can I get the database url from ?  For firestore database(which I am using) I was unable to find it.I think db url is available only for  RealTime Database ?

Comment: This example is for Firestore. Format is `'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'` Here's the full documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk

Comment: I have created a another(new) google default service account key and downloaded the JSON file and set the environment variable and now I am able to connect and get the data with the same code I posted above in the question.